# How to get complete dataset from Ms Dynamics CRM into Power BI for office365?

Tags: crm, business-intelligence, dynamics-crm-2015, powerbi

I am new to Power BI and using Power BI for office 365. I need to get all entities of my CRM organization into Power BI. I have tried getting data by using o-data feed and have succeeded to get some data But that data source does not consist all entities. In fact using Power BI desktop I have got data of all the entities of my CRM organization by using same o-data feed URL. Can anybody tell me why I can not get complete dataset in Power BI for office365 but can get complete dataset in Power BI desktop?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have followed the tutorials referred by Power BI official website to get dataset from Ms Dynamics CRM.I am creating a connection by using odata feed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Power BI Desktop, you need to use http://www.PowerBI.com to publish your datasets. We're transitioning away from the previous Power BI for Office 365 feature set.  If you're using Power BI for Office 365 you should see a prompt in the UI to 'try the new Power BI experience' or something similar.  You can click that or just login to PowerBI.com with your office 365 credentials. Both paths will take you to the same place.  Then you can upload your Power BI Desktop file and refresh it.